# Exception trying to load C++ library from Xamarin Android project with DLLImport

Tags: android, xamarin, dll, xamarin.android, dllimport

I'm trying to build some c++ libraries in order to use them from a Xamarin Android project. I have created a `Dynamic Shared Library` from Visual Studio `16.8.3`. With the following properties:

[image]

I have 2 files in the c++ library SharedObject2.cpp and SharedObject2.h with:

```
int AddCpp(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

and

```
 #pragma once

int AddCpp(int a, int b);
```

Then I compiled this project and added it to my Xamarin Android folder:

[image]

With `Build Action: AndroidNativeLibrary`

Then within the `MainActivity` of my Xamarin Android project:

```
  using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "Droid", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        [DllImport("libSharedObject2.so")]
        public static extern int AddCpp(int left, int right);

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            //breaks here
            AddCpp(2,3);
        }
    }
}
```

Any time I try to call `AddCpp(2,3);` yields:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'AddCpp assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
```

I have tried several attempts, tried to add a reference to the project itself, changed the DLLImport signature there is just no way to make this work. I have seen many other questions around StackOverflow and some links from the Xamarin team on how to include c++ libraries that looks pretty easy to do on the video but on reality is hard to do. I don't know what I might be missing but any help would be appreciated.

I attach a `.zip` solution with the projects on it so it's easy to reproduce in [this link](https://www.4shared.com/s/fwKZFCVMvea).

Thanks.

Comment: Under what name is the function exported? Is it the mangled name?

Comment: I guess the name is exported  as "AddCpp"

Comment: Well, the error message seems to be telling you that your guess is incorrect. Rather than guessing, you should find out the the truth.

Comment: Yeah I see that, but as you can see the error message is not very helpful, that's why I wrote here if someone experienced something similar or has any ideas on the proper direction.

Comment: You need to find out if the symbol is exported, and under what name. There are tools for this, but I'm not familiar with your platform. Very likely you just need to opt for C linkage with `extern "C"`. I'm trying to give you pointers on how to debug this sort of issue for yourself, which I think is the most helpful approach.